# Empty constructor function

Tags: php, oop

In a code i've come across a class which had this function at the start:

```
private function __construct() {

    }
```

Why would there be an empty function at the top? Is there any purpose to this? Or does this depend on the rest of the code? If it does could anyone give me an example in which this would be useful.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7673160/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing this achieves is to stop people instantiating the class with the `new` keyword (notice the constructor is private).

Answer (score 1):

Using a private constructor allows you to create a class that can't be instantiated. For example, when it contains only static methods. It's common, for example, with classes that implement the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).